# Deploy project based on symfony 4 to Live Server problem

Tags: php, symfony, session, deployment, session-cookies

we just buy new dedicated server on inmotion hosting

so when I'm tried to deploy a project based on Symfony 4

I got this error

`Notice: SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72) failed: Permission denied (13)`

I have already search on StackOverflow for the same problem but it does not help me

Comment: Change user to www-data or update folder permissions.

Comment: which folder should  I change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change  session.save_path in php.ini

```
 session.save_path = "/tmp"
```